# Remove element from list inside a dict Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

Hello i have a dict like this one :

```
{
   "a":{
      "a1":val,
      "a2":val
   },
   "b":{
      "b1":[
          {
             "measure":{
                 "k":"v",
                 "k1":"v"
             },
             "ts":"2020-10-12T12:12:12"
          },
          {
             "measure":{
                 "k":"v",
                 "k1":"v"
             },
             "ts":"2020-10-12T12:12:12"
          },
      ]
   }
}
```

I need to remove some dicts from the list of dicts dict["b"]["b1"]

so i imagined my code like this :

```
def epc_avionics_treatment(self,dict_data):
    i=0
    for epc1 in dict_data["b"]["b1"]:
        if (epc1["ts"]=="200-00-00T00:00:00Z"):
            del dict_data["b"]["b1"][i]
        i=i+1
    
        
    if (len(dict_data["b"]["b1"])==0):
        del dict_data["b"]["b1"]
    return dict_data
```

However elements from the list are not removed even if "ts" key equals to my criteria of removal
i also tried to assign dict["b"]["b1"] to vars but it has no impact.

Comment: value of ts in dict is "2020-10-12T12:12:12" there is no exact matching condition hence this data won't get removed, change your if condition epc1["ts"] matching to "2020-10-12T12:12:12"
if (epc1["ts"]=="2020-10-12T12:12:12"):
            del dict_data["b"]["b1"][i]
also you don't need to increment value of i

Comment: this is a generic example...

Answer (score 1):

It is happening because when you are deleting the element you dont need to increment your index var.
**Working example:**

```
def epc_avionics_treatment(dict_data):
    i=0
    while i<len(dict_data["b"]["b1"]):
        if (dict_data["b"]["b1"][i]["ts"]=="200-00-00T00:00:00Z"):
            del dict_data["b"]["b1"][i]
            i-=1
        i=i+1
    
        
    if (len(dict_data["b"]["b1"])==0):
        del dict_data["b"]["b1"]
    return dict_data
```

Comment: thanks it worked for the first part, my list "b1" is now empty so the second test returns true so i shlould delete the key from the dict but instead i have a key error : "b1"

Comment: @FrozzenFinger
I don't have any errors with code from your example, so can you please show me the code that you get the error with

Comment: this is it (my dict is a bit more complicated) the elements in the list has been well removed like expected so now in my dict i have "b1":[] and when it comes to `del dict_data["b"]["b1"]` i got he error `KeyError : "b1"`

Comment: @FrozzenFinger
You can get `KeyError` only if your `dict_data["b"]` dictionary does not contain "b1" key. You can handle this error with `try/catch` or you can add this line `dict_data["b"]["b1"]=dict_data["b"].get("b1",[])` before your  `if (len(dict_data["b"]["b1"])==0):` if statement. If you can to show your full code with dict and error I think I'll help you.

Comment: yeah i know i've printed the dict after commenting the delete key part and it exists !!!

Comment: more over the programe gets in this condition `if (len(dict_data["b"]["b1"])==0)` that means that key "b1" exists in "bdict"

Comment: my bad i had a typo ^^

Comment: I was happy to help. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Your code is experiencing a logical error. When you delete a node by following commands

```
del dict_data["b"]["b1"][i]
```

and then increasing the i, you are going wrong because you are skipping one another node. I'm going to explain it in the below :

```
items = [a1,a2,a3,a4,a5]

i=3 // So items[2] : a3

// lets delete items[i]

del items[i] // a3 has been removed.

// now , items[i] is a4 ( i have not increased i yet ), so what happen if i increase the i ? 
i = i + 1 // now items[i] is a5 and i have skipped a4

//if i delete items[i], a5 would be removed and not a4
```